# Typescript type for getting class properties from static method on a parent class

Tags: typescript, class, oop, types

Let's say you have these two classes:

```
class Form {
    static fields(){
       return []; // some magic happens here
    }
}

class UserForm extends Form{
    email: string;
}

const formFields = UserForm.fields();
```

What type can I add for the static `fields` method in order to get a list of `UserForm` properties, in this case, only the email property as `("email")[]`?

I tried using `keyof T` but it doesn't give me the desired answer:

```
static fields<T>(this: T): (keyof T)[] {
       return []; // some magic happens here
    }
```

This returns `("prototype" | "fields")[]` instead of `("email")[]`.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance of `this` and return `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(instance)`

```
class Form {
    foo: string = 'bar'
    static fields<T>(): (keyof T)[]{
       return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new this) as (keyof T)[]
    }
}

class UserForm extends Form{
    email: string = '';
}

const formFields = UserForm.fields<UserForm>();
console.log(formFields)
```

Working repl.it project: https://repl.it/@HarunYlmaz/ts-property-list

Comment: yes, But what is the exact type of the method? From you code I see it's `string[]`. I don't want the fields() method to return `string[]`. I want the exact fields. Like `("email" | "foo")[]`

Comment: Do you want the method to return the types of the properties?

Comment: No. I just want the method to return the current class's properties/fields

Comment: This solution returns the names of the properties of the class. I guess I'm not fully understanding the result you want to get.

Comment: I want the TYPE of the method to show the fields name. I don't really care what the method returns. I want to set the type of the method to return a class's fields.

Comment: I updated the answer. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: Yes, this will work. But there is a redundancy now: you have to write `UserForm` twice. Isn't there a way to infer the T from the class itself without passing it as a generic type?

Comment: Aah. I think I got it: `fields<T>(this: new (...args: any[]) => T): (keyof T)[]`